# Error during executing Android command: Ant Jar

Tags: android, ant, cordova, jar

So this is the error I get when I try to run any command except "create".

An error occurred during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform: Command failed to execute : ant jar

These are my PATHS

```
PATH "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin"

JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"

ANT_HOME "C:\java\ant\apache-ant-1.8.2"
```

My OS: Windows 8

PS: I've gone through every single post that stated this error but, none of the responses solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was a phonegap version related issue. When I updated it was all fine.